# Adding a new component removes existing registrations of all components

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have the following code that I'm using in a Web API DelegatingHandler

```
var registration = RegistrationBuilder
    .ForDelegate((c, p) => sessionData)
    .ExternallyOwned()
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerRequest()
    .CreateRegistration();

    var componentRegistry = ((AutofacWebApiDependencyScope) request.GetDependencyScope()).LifetimeScope.ComponentRegistry;

    componentRegistry.Register(registration, true);
```

Before the registration I have a couple of components registered but after adding the new one, all the other registrations are gone and only the one I added exists. Does anyone know why this is happening? I looked into the Autofac code and could not find the reason as to why this is would happen, but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

**UPDATE 1**

So after a bit more digging, initially I have 18 registrations, after adding the new one I have basically that one, and if I try to use the same scope to resolve that component, there's no issues whatsoever. Later on during the execution, when the Controller is hit, the scope has 18 registrations still but not the one I added. Is it possible that I'm adding the registration to a different scope?! I checked it and the tag is indeed the "AutofacWebRequest" one.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds normal, do you have any problem ? :-)

Comment: Well, I expected to have 19 registrations not 18, unless I am missing something out, which might just be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this was a silly mistake. In this object all properties were being injected and in one of them, in the 'set' I was doing some other work that depended in other property being injected, but since not all the properties are injected at the same time, while one was being set the other one that was still null.